# having difficulty with class definition and calling

Tags: c++, class, opencv

In c++ ( with openCV), I defined my call in the header file as follows:

```
class myClass
{
public: 
    myClass ( cv::Mat& _mat );
    void initClass ( cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& mask, myClass& src, myClass& dst );
}
```

Then in the corresponding "cpp" file, I defined it like this:

```
myClass::myClass ( cv::Mat& _mat )
{
    model = _model;
     ....
 }

void myClass::initClass ( cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& mask, myClass& src, myClass& dst )
{
    //some work here
}
```

Then I included its header file in the "main.cpp", and tried to call it like this:

```
cv::Mat test ( height, width, CV_8UC3 );
cv::Mat test2 ( height, width, CV_8UC3 );
myClass::myClass auM ( test );
myClass::myClass buM ( test );
myClass::initClass ( img, img, auM, buM );
```

But it gives out error in both the last two lines, saying:

> > cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "myClass::myClass" is intended

for the lines

```
myClass::myClass auM ( test );
myClass::myClass buM ( test );
```

and

> > a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

for the line

```
    myClass::initClass ( img, img, auM, buM );
```

I searched and found it was something related to my class definition, but I couldn't solve it. Could someone help me?

Comment: what is `call` in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have another look at a tutorial on object oriented programming in c++, as for instance [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) one. As juanchopanza stated, your specific problem is based on the difference between static and non-static members. Information on this can be found in tutorial page "Classes (II)".

In short: non-static members (the most commonly used type) belong to objects (instances) of  a class. This means you need to instantiate the class, before you can access the variable or call the function. Like this:

```
MyClass myObject();
myObject.nonStaticMemberFunction();
```

Static members on the other hand belong to a class and not to a specific object of this class, they can be called by accessing the name of the class. Like that:

```
MyClass::staticMemberFunction();
```

This is just a rough overview on how you can call these different types of functions, have a look at the tutorial, to really get the difference.

There are some more things I would change in your code, I don't always get what you're trying to achieve, but here's how I would do it:

```
// Never heard of a "call" keyword, must be a #define?!
// By convention most people use upper case class names, to
// distinguish classes from objects.
class MyClass 
{
public: 
    MyClass ( cv::Mat& _mat );
    // If your convention is to use underscores to mark function parameters,
    // you should stick to it.
    void initClass ( cv::Mat& _img, cv::Mat& _mask, myClass& _src, myClass& _dst );
}

MyClass::MyClass ( cv::Mat& _mat )
{
    // I don't know where these variables come from, but again:
    // if you use underscores, to mark function parameters, you
    // shouldn't use them with other variable types.
    model = _model;
    ....
 }

void MyClass::initClass ( cv::Mat& _img, cv::Mat& _mask, myClass& _src, myClass& _dst )
{
    //some work here
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    cv::Mat test ( height, width, CV_8UC3 );
    cv::Mat test2 ( height, width, CV_8UC3 );
    MyClass auM ( test );
    MyClass buM ( test );
    // as "initClass is a non-static member, you have to instantiate
    // MyClass before calling it:
    MyClass cuM ( test );
    cuM.initClass ( img, img, auM, buM );
}
```

The conventions I mentioned are not important for a program to run. Nevertheless, I strongly recommend you get used to them early on, as they improve readability and maintainability a lot.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for instantiating a class taking one constructor argument is

```
myClass auM(test);
```

You do not need to "call" `myClass::myClass`. As for the menber function `initClass`, you are calling it as if it were a static method. A non-static member function needs to be called on an instance:

```
auM.someMethod( arg1, arg2, .... );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to construct two objects of myClass, auM and buM then you should be doing

```
myClass auM ( test );
myClass buM ( test );
```